# Проблема с списком

Tags: python

Здравстуйте! Имеется код вида:

```
freqsdepth = [2,20,40,80,100,200,400,600]
thickness = [58,250,600]
surfs = [] #0 58 307 908

for i in range(len(thickness)):
    if i == 0:
        surfs.append(0)
        surfs.append(thickness[i])
    else:
        surfs.append(surfs[i]+thickness[i])

listofpairs=[]

for current, next in zip(surfs, surfs[1:]):
    listofpairs.append([current,next])

#listofpairs = [[0, 58], [58, 308], [308, 908]]

for pair in listofpairs:
    for d in freqsdepth:
        if freqsdepth[d] in range(pair[0],pair[1]):
            print("True")
        else:
            print("False")
```

Однако выдает ошибку:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
True
  File "C:/Users/HP/PycharmProjects/sklearn/intervals.py", line 22, in <module>
    if freqsdepth[d] in range(pair[0],pair[1]):
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Не могу разобраться. Буду очень признателен. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for d in freqsdepth:
    if freqsdepth[d] in range(pair[0],pair[1]):
```

Здесь `d` это перебор самих значений, а не индексов.

Исправь на `if d in range(pair[0],pair[1]):`

Вот и получается, что сразу второе значение `freqsdepth[20]` дает выход за границу индексов массива.

Comment: есть какая-то разница между использованием в данном случае выражения range или x<=d<=y?

Comment: @AlexeyPiskunov логика точно не изменится, но вкладываемый смыл будет легче понять при чтении кода. Кстати, в `range(1, 5) = 1, 2, 3, 4`, т.е. правая граница не входит в отличии от `1 <= d <= 5`, либо `range(x, y + 1)`